# Facescomponents loads very slow

Tags: jsf, custom-component

I have component like this (simplified version):

```
@FacesComponent
public class MyComponent extends UINamingContainer {

public MyData getMyData() {
    // Here I want to fetch some data from DB to satisfy
    // element
}

}
```

This component is used few times in my form, so everything is loading very slow. Is there any way to load it in parallel or speed up in another way? Thanks.

Comment: How exactly did you conclude that the problem is in the JSF side and not in the database interaction side? Is it faster when DB code is executed in a standalone application? Is it as fast as when the desired data is hardcoded? Regardless, DB interaction belongs in the model, not the view.

Comment: Did you read about the problems implementing Data Access into getter methods can carry on?